# Evaluated range with `Int` function when range contains non integer values

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, vba

I would like my loop to evaluate values in a range and proceed if the value is non-zero and a whole integer. My range also contains alpha-numeric values and I would like those to be ignored.

My loop is getting stuck when I hit one of those alpha-numeric values. How do I fix?

My code:

```
Dim r2 As Range
Dim fnd As Range
Dim Answer3 As String
    For Each r2 In WorkRng2
        If r2.Value <> "" And WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(r2.Value) Then
            If r2.Value = Int(r2.Value) Then
            Set fnd = WorkRng1.Find(what:=r2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If fnd Is Nothing Then
                'nothing found
                Answer3 = MsgBox("Cannot proceed! Major Task " & r2.Value & " could not be found in invoice review file!", vbOKOnly, "Question!")
                    If Answer3 = vbOK Then
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                    'fnd holds the cell that was found
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Also, `WorkRng1` and `WorkRng2` are public variables.

Comment: You need two `IF...`. First to check not blank and a number (`If r2.Value <> "" And WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(r2.Value)).` and then check if the number is an int (`If r2.Value = Int(r2.Value)...)`

Comment: @AlexP did I do it right? I made the big edit. when i run the code i'm not getting the expect result, it seems to continue on without stopping and showing the message box

Comment: Put a break point on that line and debug and see what the value for `fnd` is when the MsgBox is skipped.

Comment: @JacobH I added `LookAt:=xlWhole` and converted formatting to text for both ranges and it works now. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering how I solved with the help of comments below here is my working code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WorkRng1.NumberFormat = "@"
    WorkRng2.Parent.Activate
    WorkRng2.NumberFormat = "@"
    WorkRng1.Parent.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim r2 As Range
Dim fnd As Range
Dim Answer3 As String
    For Each r2 In WorkRng2
        If r2.Value <> "" And WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(r2.Value) Then
            If r2.Value = Int(r2.Value) And r2.Value <> "9" Then
            Set fnd = WorkRng1.Find(what:=r2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If fnd Is Nothing Then
                'nothing found
                Answer3 = MsgBox("Cannot proceed! Major Task '" & r2.Value & "' could not be found in invoice review file!", vbOKOnly, "Question!")
                    If Answer3 = vbOK Then
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                    'fnd holds the cell that was found
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WorkRng1.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    WorkRng2.Parent.Activate
    WorkRng2.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    WorkRng1.Parent.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```